# How do I end my custom action on assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a very simple action that just gives me some status and then I want to end it, no conversation, nothing else, just get the status and end it. Right now I'm doing this:

```
agent.add(message1);
agent.add(message2);
agent.end('done');
```

I've also tried (as you'll see on the code below just doing `agent.end(completeMessage);` but assistant keeps waiting for me to do more, my action doesn't end.

I've made a totally simple sample to demostrate, `test intent` is the one that has the `end()` call:

[image]

Code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

const fetch = require("node-fetch");

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  function testIntent(agent) {
    agent.end('done');
  }

 intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('test intent', testIntent);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Anyone have any ideas of how I can make my action just totally end when I called `test intent`?

Comment: Can you be clear about exactly which library you're using? (Showing the require and the package.json files)

Comment: I'm just using their DialogFlow inline editor, no idea what their package.json looks like? but I've added the require lines.

Comment: I should mention, I just started on this action a few days ago so I'm assuming it is using whatever the latest default is for the inline editor.

Comment: Can you update the question to illustrate exactly what *is* happening when end is called? Is there anything logged? Can you show the rest of the Intent Handler where this is happening?

Comment: Going to add my code, hopefully that will explain things. Basically once I've called `testIntent` using a Google Home device, it just sits there waiting for more and every so often it says sorry I couldn't understand or something like that, eventually it gives up. I hear `done` though so the `end` method worked.

Comment: Any idea? is there maybe no way to close an action from inside the action itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the dialogflow-fulfillment library with Actions on Google, you can only have two simple responses (text or SSML strings). Since your code calls `agent.end()` after two messages have already been set, it may be ignored.

Instead you can call it as

```
agent.add(message1);
agent.end(message2);
```

The documentation for `agent` is for the [WebhookClient](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client) object. If you want to skip the library, there is also the [webhook response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_response) JSON documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the link, that really helps, however doing `end` on the second message didn't help. Could this be because I am doing this from a function that returns a `promise`. Essentially I do all this `async`and return the `promise` on when my function is called by the intent. It appears to work but then it just sits there waiting for me to say more things.

Comment: Is changed it to one line `agent.end(message1 +" and "+ message2)` and that still didn't do it.

Comment: Your example code doesn't show a Promise. That should have worked, so I'm at a loss right now what is happening and haven't had time to try and reproduce.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention, once I had the thought that it was an issue with the `promise` I just made a super ultra simple example, all it does is call `agent.end("done")` but even that doesn't end my action.